# Open API VK, проблемы с методом isAppUser

Tags: vkontakte-api, javascript

Хочу проверить установил ли пользователь приложение или нет, но при загрузке страницы сам метод isAppUser срабатывает только при 2 вызове.

Т.е. например

```
<a id="start" href="#">Start Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#start').click(function() {

        VK.Api.call('isAppUser',{}, function(r) {   
            if (r.response == 1)
            {
               // установил
            } else {
                // не установил
            }

        });

});

</script>
```

какое то действие если пользователь установил или нет приложение срабатывает только со 2 клика, и вообще сам вызов метода происходит со 2 клика...

Попробовал исправить таким образом

```
function tester()
{
    var mytest;

        VK.Api.call('isAppUser',{}, function(r) {   
            if (r.response == 1)
            {
                mytest = '1';
            } else {
                mytest = '0';
            }

        });

    test.innerHTML = test.innerHTML+'<br>mytest = '+mytest;

    if (typeof mytest != 'undefined')
    {
        test.innerHTML = test.innerHTML+'<br>Ура!11';
    } else {
        test.innerHTML = test.innerHTML+'<br>timeout...';
        setTimeout(tester, 3000);
    } 
}

tester();
```

Однако это ситуацию не исправляет, всегда пишет undefined... Что можете посоветовать ?

Comment: А где у вас Api.init() срабатывает? Может оно не упевает прогрузиться на момент первого клика.
Первый код выглядит вполне валидно. Как вариант, попробуйте обернуть навешивание обработчика в document.ready.
А вообще я бы залез в дебагер, поставил точку останова на обработчике клика и посмотрел бы, заходит ли туда поток при первом клике.

Второй кусок кода вообще бредовый. Естественно mytester в строке 
test.innerHTML = test.innerHTML+'<br>mytest = '+mytest;
Будет неопределен, даже если вызов Api.call сработает.

Comment: Я и так обернул в document.ready, инициализация проходит там же. Вот залил пример https://dl.dropbox.com/u/78272961/app.html (не работает на дропбоксе) При 1 клике пишет просто clicked..., при 2 clicked, isAppUser init и установил или нет.

По 2 куску кода, почему всегда будет undefined ? Потому что test не определен ? У меня он есть, при постинге сюда затерялся =)

Comment: mytest будет неопределен, так как порядок действий такой
1. var mytest - тут он неопределен
2. манипуляции с mytest - неопределен
3. вызов кэллбека из Api - уже может быть определен

Comment: Еще у вас может вызываться Api.init  до того как прогрузится либа ВК. Нужно сделать асинхронно (у них есть пример как это делать)

Comment: Попробовал асинхронно, ситуация такая же.

Comment: Заметил еще такую штуку, что если приложение установлено, то все нормально работает с 1 раза.